# Is this a good use case of the Strategy Pattern?

Tags: php, design-patterns, language-agnostic, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern

I'm working with an application that needs to receive several videos, and display them on a particular page, currently these videos can only be from YouTube, due to an implementation that does not allow other providers, because the code to get the video data, as a preview image, was placed directly in the View Helper responsible for displaying the video.

I want to change this structure to make it easy to add new providers, such as Vimeo, and I think the Strategy pattern would be the ideal, I would have in my View Helper the method `setVideoUrl( string $url )`, this method would call the method `getProviderStrategy( string $url )` from the `class VideoProviderFactory`, this factory class would then return, if available, the strategy class, that implements the `interface VideoProvider`, for the provider of the video url.

What do you think? This is correct? I Need to change something?

Detail: I initially thought about putting a switch to choose the strategy directly into the View Helper, but after reading this question: I [Strategy Pattern with no 'switch' statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834091/strategy-pattern-with-no-switch-statements) I saw that I was wrong, then the `class VideoProviderFactory` showed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like a very good design, with proper separation of responsibilities.

To give you some more food for thought, consider *how* the factory will decide which strategy to create. Later when you want to add *another* strategy, what needs to change? First, you'd create a new `VideoProvider`, then you'd have to change the factory `switch` statement (as you've described) and include the selection logic for this new strategy. Now, this is perfectly fine most of the time, but what if you'd like to add the new strategy without changing the factory?

One way is to have a factory-like interface with a method that decides based on the URL if it should create a specific `VideoProvider`; let's call it `VideoProviderMatcher` (pseudo-code):

```
interface VideoProviderMatcher {
  bool understands(url)
  VideoProvider create()
}
```

Now, this interface knows if it understands a URL and also how to create the `VideoProvider` that relates to it. When you need to create a new strategy, you implement both the `VideoProvider` and the related `VideoProviderMatcher`. As for the factory, it changes to encapsulate a list of `VideoProviderMatcher`s and delegates to the first that understands the given URL, using a *chain of responsibility* (pseudo-code):

```
class VideoProviderFactory {
  List[VideoProviderMatcher] matchers
  void registerMatcher(VideoProviderMatcher matcher) {
    matchers.add(matcher)
  }
  VideoProvider getVideoProviderFor(url) {
    foreach (matcher in matchers) {
      if (matcher.understands(url)) return matcher.create()
    }
  }
}
```

Now the only code that needs to change is the code that creates the factory in the first place. Ideally, it has a list of `VideoProviderMatcher`s that it uses to populate the factory and you just add another item to the list.

Now, is this worth it? I'd say it depends on the complexity of the matching logic, the will to encapsulate the URL matching together with the video provider, the desire to keep the factory stable when new strategies are added, and the rate at which new strategies are added to the solution.

Comment: Good one. The only thing I don't understand is why we would need the intermediate VideoProviderMatcher interface. Couldn't that functionality be implemented as part of the VideoProvider class?

Comment: @hennes IMO, VideoProviderMatcher makes the url understanding more abstract. The matcher can then accept implementation to basically filter out URLs on various conditions like on domain / part of url / ..

Comment: This solution gave me great ideas, but for this application I mentioned, I will continue with the switch, since there is no need to add new providers regularly (KISS), but for other projects I can see great places to implement this, and that was exactly one of my doubts, how to have a factory without a switch. Thanks man.